# sql datetime column - insert time as 00:00:00.000

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I want to insert `datetime` column in `sql server` with time as `2014-09-20 00:00:00.000`

In the code the date also contains the time like this :-
`2014-09-20 10:40:00.000`

When inserting this in sql, i need to convert time part to `2014-09-20 00:00:00.000`.

When i do the conversion like this :-

```
DateTime ts = DateTime.Now;
ts = new DateTime ( ts.Year, ts.Month, ts.Day, 0, 0, 0 ) ;
```

Result :-

```
12/7/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

How to make time 00:00:00.0000

Linq Insert Code :-
`item.InOutDate` contains `Date + Time`

```
item.InOutDate = new DateTime ( item.InOutDate.Year, item.InOutDate.Month, item.InOutDate.Day, 0, 0, 0 );
ctx.tblTable.Add(item);
```

Comment: It'll be `00:00:00.0000` when you insert it in the DB. 12:00:00 AM is the same as 00:00:00.0000.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. 00:00:00:0000 is the same as 12:00:00 AM. By the way is there any reason why that would make a difference?

Comment: I believe there's nothing wrong with your insert. As I've said before, 12:00:00 AM is the same as 00:00:00.0000.

Comment: @FelixPamittan You are correct...the value gets saved in SQL as 00:00:00.000

Comment: If you're inserting into a `datetime` column, just insert the value already. What's stored is a compact binary representation of the datetime data. It doesn't **have** a format when its stored. Just pass it across as a `DateTime` parameter from your C# code and let ADO.Net deal with translating .NET's `DateTime` (which also doesn't *have* a format) into SQL Server's `datetime`.

Answer (score 2):

### You don't need to do anything.

You are confusing about between value of a `DateTime` and *textual* representation of a `DateTime`. A `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. Format concept *only* matters when you get it's string representation.

For example; what is the difference between those?

```
12/7/2015 12:00:00 AM
12/7/2015 00:00:00
```

As a value (calculated based their [`Ticks` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)), they are equal<sup>1</sup>. Only difference is their string representations. First one is 12-hour clock format and second one is 24-hour clock format.

On the other hand, SQL Server keeps `DateTime` values as a binary in [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) and [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) column types. That means, just pass your `DateTime` value *directly* to your [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) and SQL Server saves it's as a `datetime` [which is mapped](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

By the way, you can use [`Today` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) of a `DateTime` to get date part with `00:00:00` as a time part.

```
DateTime ts = DateTime.Today;
```

<sup>1</sup>: Of course I assume 12 is month and 7 is day.

Answer (score 0):

While inserting into database you can use the below code directly instead of doing the conversion using C# code:

```
insert into table1(col1) values (dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),0))
```

Comment: I am using Linq for inserting records

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COLUMNS)
VALUES (DATEADD(DD,0,0)+DATEDIFF(DD,0,GETDATE()))
```